# Unable to parse environment variable in another module

Tags: haskell

I have 2 modules and each of them I read environment variables.  In the main module it's being read correctly and in another one not:

```
--Main module

import Module2
startApp :: IO ()
startApp = do
  port <- liftM read $ getEnv "PORT" -- ok
  print $ "Listening the port " ++ (show port) ++ "..." -- ok
  run port app


-- it's not called immediately
myFMain = do
  Module2.myF 
  --.........



--Module2
----...........

myF :: IO MyData
myF = do
  env <- liftM read $ getEnv "ENV" :: IO String
  print $ "ENV is " ++ (show env) -- error Prelude.read: no parse
  --.........
```

I run it as `PORT=3344 ENV=development stack exec my-app-exe`. Might it be because it's not in the main module and it's thus loaded when I first call it? It's called when a user requests a url.

Comment: Could you give us a minimal "working" example i.e. cabal file and stack.yaml. it is not clear to me that/how the second function is ever called at all. Do you have two executables or one.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe, one exec. it's called from `myFMain`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getEnv` returns `IO String`, why do you call `read` on its result? You can use it right away.

If you really want this, execute `show "asd"` and look what string should look like to be correctly parsed by `read`.

Comment: `Couldn't match expected type ‘IO a0’
                with actual type ‘m0 a10 -> m0 r0’
` without "read"

Comment: You don't need `liftM` there too. Just `env <- getEnv "ENV"`.

Comment: why do I need liftM in `port <- liftM read $ getEnv "PORT` then?

Comment: Because `getEnv` has type `IO String` and `read` operates on `String`. With `liftM` you make `read` operate on `IO String` at the cost of returning `IO a`. Alternative way to write this: `env0 <- getEnv "PORT"; let env = read env0`.

Comment: Presumably, `run` takes an `Int` as its first argument. In order to convert an `IO String` value to an `Int`, you first need to convert it to `IO Int`, which is what `liftM read` does.